# Electromagnetic waves and photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, photons

Electromagnetic waves are photons or photons cause electromagnetic waves ? Its said that when charges are accelerated we get electric and magnetic field that carries energy but then they say that this energy is transferred in the form of photons so its confusing.

Comment: Passing an static field appears magnetic.

Comment: Alex, since the question was closed as a duplicate I gave [an answer here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/253957#253957).

Comment: just i would ask one more thing. does every photon has its own EM field ? your answer was really amazing. @HolgerFiedler

Comment: really you have cleared all questions in my mind on this topic. @HolgerFiedler

Comment: now i guess photon is an electromagnetic radiation/wave in particle form.  and oscillating charges create oscillating photons or oscillating electromagnetic field/wave/radiation. right ?

Comment: do all accelerating charges produce oscillating electromagnetic field or only oscillating charges produce oscillating electromagnetic field ?

Comment: All accelerated charges are radiating. If you want read http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242873/how-is-the-electromagnetic-field-made/242975#242975 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241122/what-is-the-nature-of-the-magnetic-fields/241835#241835

Comment: @HolgerFiedler i am sorry my native language is not english so its hard for me to read that much. will you please tell briefly that what will be the difference between the EM waves caused by the oscillating charges and just by accelerating charge. you said that "Using a wave generator it is possible to create oscillating EM radiation. Such radiations are called radio waves. " thats where i get confused that do only oscillating charges cause oscillating EM radiation while just accelerating particles will not cause oscillating waves and will cause radiation in anyother form ?